# different order of command line options in a command affecting my output

Tags: c, getopt-long

i am making a program in c that accepts command line arguments like --version , --download.

when i do this :

```
$program --version --download file
```

the program outputs the version and downloads the file. But when i do this:

```
$program --download --version file
```

the program considers `--version` to be the argument to `--download`.

I have used `getopt_long()` function for parsing the command line arguments. Here's a snippet from my code:

```
while ((ch = getopt_long(argc, argv, "d:g:hv", longoptions, &optindex)) != -1 )
{
    switch(ch)
    {
            case 'd' :
                if ( optarg )
                    printf("Downloading %s...\n" , optarg);
                iso(optarg);
                break ;

            case 'g' :
                if ( optarg )
                    printf("Downloading glug-mirror automation script for %s ...\n", optarg);
                getscript(optarg);
                break ; 

            case 'v' : 
                printf("glug version 1.0.0 ( NIT Hamirpur)\n");
                break ;

            case 'h' :
                usage(status);
                break ;

            default :
                status  = 2 ; 
               usage(status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**`getoptlong()`** is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

- The format-string `"d:g:hv"` implies that the parameters `d` and `g` require a value.
- Anything specified following a command-line parameter is consider a value being passed to it.

You should run your program as

```
$program --download file --version
```

Checkout this [**detailed example**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html) demonstrating the various aspects of using `getoptlong()`.

---

> How `rm` can handle the differing position of its cmd-line params?

Apparently because `rm`'s parameters (`r`, `v` etc.) do NOT accept any values as arguments. Thus `directory` does not get passed to any of them but rather is a separate cmd-line argument on its own. You can confirm this from the [**source-code of rm**](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/rm.c;h=4b87c12e8996dc4a7ef3d7c2aa6e0988d4614332;hb=HEAD).

To do something similar for your program, you will need to modify the **optstring** to `"dghv"` and handle the parameter `"file"` separately.

Comment: the rm command can be used like this:  
rm -rv directory  
rm -r directory -v    
rm -vr directory    
rm-rv directory  

so i want my program to be this much flexible.....

Comment: `rm` does this by treating `directory` as a separate param; **not** a value associated with any of the other cmd-line params. Updated the answer with details of the same.